# Will Django use previously-evaluated results when applying additional filters to a query set?

Tags: django, django-orm

Let's say I need to do some work both on a set of model objects, as well as a subset of the first set:

```
things = Thing.objects.filter(active=True)
for thing in things:                # (1)
    pass # do something with each `thing`

special_things = things.filter(special=True)
for thing in special_things:        # (2)
    pass # do something more with these things
```

My understanding is that at point (1) marked in the code above, an actual SQL query something like `SELECT * FROM things_table WHERE active=1` will get executed against the database. The [QuerySet documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#all) also says:

> When a QuerySet is evaluated, it typically caches its results.

Now my question is, what happens at point (2) in the example Python code above?

Will Django execute a second SQL query, something like `SELECT * FROM things_table WHERE active=1 AND special=1`?

Or, will it use the cached result from earlier, automatically doing for me behind the scenes something like the more optimal `filter(lambda d: d.special == True, things)`, i.e. avoiding a needless second trip to the database?

Either way, is the current behavior guaranteed (by documentation or something) or should I not rely on it? For example, it is not only a point of optimization, but could also make a possible logic difference if the database table is modified by another thread/process between the two potential queries.

Answer (score 1):

It will execute a second SQL query. `filter` creates a new queryset, which doesn't copy the results cache.

As for guarantees - well, the docs specify that `filter` returns a new queryset object. I think you can be confident that that new queryset won't have cached results yet. As further support, the "when are querysets evaluated" docs suggest using `.all()` to get a new queryset if you want to pick up possibly changed results:

> If the data in the database might have changed since a QuerySet was
>   evaluated, you can get updated results for the same query by calling
>   all() on a previously evaluated QuerySet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and glad you saw my edit re. documentation!